# Push for array not working inside loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've seen people ask the same questions but the answers to them are not quite what I'm looking for. I know this might be a basic question, but the push function in my Javascript code is not working.

I have an array of strings like ["hey","how","are","you"].

I want to encrypt these words and save them in another array.

I've tried using a for loop as a very basic measure and I thought this would work. I'm attaching my code below.

```
var tag = document.getElementById('file_id')
function decryption(){
    var arr = tag.value.split(",");
    var encrypted_array = {};
    for (let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){

        var abc = CryptoJS.SHA1(arr[i].toString());
        console.log(abc.toString());
        encrypted_array.push(abc.toString());
    }
    console.log("woah");
    console.log(arr);
    console.log(encrypted_array);
}

$('#decryption_form').submit(function(e){
    decryption();
    alert("submitted")

});
```

I don't want any complex codes, I just want to know why I am getting an error saying encrypted_array.push is not a function and how can I correct it?

Comment: You have to declare your `encrypted_array` as an array not object.

Comment: `var encrypted_array = [];`

Comment: Sorry! Please close this question.

Comment: Deleted my answer, try closing now @coder123

Comment: You can delete now. (Thanks @Dominic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define var encrypted_array as []

```
var tag = document.getElementById('file_id') function decryption(){
    var arr = tag.value.split(",");

    var encrypted_array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){

        var abc = CryptoJS.SHA1(arr[i].toString());
        console.log(abc.toString());
        encrypted_array.push(abc.toString());
    }
    console.log("woah");
    console.log(arr);
    console.log(encrypted_array); }

$('#decryption_form').submit(function(e){
    decryption();
    alert("submitted")

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your array like this:

```
 var encrypted_array = [];
```

Not like this:

```
var encrypted_array = {};
```